# Configure Docker services to build multiple images

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am experimenting with Docker and I have the following folder structure:

```
- mtg2
 - docker-compose.yml (file)
 - mgt-dash (contains angular-cli app)
 - server (contains node/express server)
   - release (contains index.js)
```

Each sub-folder has its own `Dockerfile` and I am trying to figure out how to use the `docker-compose.yml` file to declare 2 services so that when I run `docker-compose up` it builds both images.

So far my [`docker-compose.yml`](https://gist.github.com/webseo-onilne/557fe7b89f67be91945aea9f46f2715a) file contains the following:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    app:
        image: 'mtg-dash'
        build: '.'
        ports:
            - 3000:80

    node:
        image: 'node-server'
        build: '.'
        ports:
            - 4000:80
```

The Docker docs are pretty vast and I am not entirely sure where to start.

---

So far I have tried moving both docker files from their respective folders and combining them into a single [`Dockerfile`](https://gist.github.com/webseo-onilne/bf7eaa5d49ba398c18a73cc54f61f251) in the root as follows:

```
# For angular app
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY mgt-dash/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY mgt-dash/dist/mgt-dash .


# For node express server
FROM node:8
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/release

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY server/package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

With this configuration, the angular app (sometimes) builds fine and runs as expected on port `3000` but the node server on port `4000` does not work and I get the following error while running `docker-compose up`:

> Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/release/index.js'

The full terminal output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/webseo-onilne/882013b6f197f216ee1a0ad80b391e0a)

If I understand this correctly it is because docker is not able to find the `index.js` file which runs the server.

So my question is how do I set this up so that when I run `docker-compose up` it builds both images? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

---

I should note that I am using the latest version of Docker and node `v8.11.1` on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `docker-compose` file to build using the `Dockerfile` inside each folder:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    app:
        build: 
            context: ./mgt-dash
        ports:
            - 3000:3000

    node:
        build: 
            context: ./server
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works - no more errors when running `docker-compose up`, but the node server (port `4000`) does not seem to be running. I think I am missing something fundamental here, so I will accept your answer because it does actually solve my question. However if you have any thoughts on why the node server does not run I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my response, in this case the first argument is the port you will use to access the image and the second argument is the port you are exposing in the Dockerfile. For example, if you want to access the node server on port 80 but the image is exposing the 4000, you need to write `80:4000`

Comment: Ok great, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad to help :)